# toggle UIButton text programmatically with a conditional statement

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Here's my code (it's wrapped in an IBAction that is called when the button is pressed):

```
if (myButton.currentTitle == @"test") {

    [myButton setTitle:@"test2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

if (myButton.currentTitle == @"test2") {

    [myButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

I want the UIButton text to toggle when pressed (if text = "test" then change to "test2" and when pressed if text = "test2" change to "test").

I do have an IBOutlet connected for myButton and the the IBAction connected to myButton--so I am pretty sure it isn't a problem with my connections.

For some reason this isn't working, I'm sure I am missing something very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use isEqualToString: instead of ==

Comment: this works perfectly. thanks (had to delete comment and wait to accept after 9 minutes? weird.)

Answer (score 2):

This is because you lack a control statement that skips the second `if` when the first one succeeds. When you come into the block with `"test"`, you switch it to `"test2"`, and then the second condition succeeds immediately, and you turn `"test2"` back into `"@test"`.

You can an an `else` to fix this, but you can skip the `if` altogether by using an `NSArray` that maps the current state to the new state.

```
// This should be made static, and initialized only once
NSDictionary *nextTitle = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"test", @"test2", @"test2", @"test", nil];

// This line does the toggling
[myButton setTitle:[nextTitle valueForKey:myButton.currentTitle] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: i don't think this is issue out here.

Comment: @RIP Once the OP figures out the `isEqualToString`, he'll immediately come to the missing `else` issue :)

Comment: i wish you could accept two answers. i did forget the 'else' and did run into this problem immediately after. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ([myButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"test"]) {

  [myButton setTitle:@"test2" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 }

if ([myButton.currentTitle isEqualToString:@"test2"]) {

   [myButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Hope, this will help you...

Answer (score 0):

Comparing user-visible strings is generally considered bad practice (and becomes tedious when you need to do i18n), especially with string literals since it's vulnerable to typos.

If you're just going to *toggle* between two states, the easiest thing to do is to use the `UIControl.selected` property (corresponding to `UIControlStateSelected`):

```
// In init
[myButton setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"test2" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[myButton setTitle:@"test2" forState:UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted];

// Toggle
myButton.selected = !myButton.selected;
```

It also makes the code a lot cleaner when you when you decide to toggle the button image/background/text colours too.

Note the slight gotcha: If you don't set the title for `UIControlStateSelected|UIControlStateHighlighted` it will use the title for `UIControlStateNormal` when the button is both selected and highlighted (touched).

Answer (score -1):

When comparing strings to each other try using `if([str1 compare:str2] == NSOrderedSame)`

Comment: I tend to avoid `-compare:` as it's very easy to accidentally do `if ([a compare:b])`. Also, I try to avoid comparing it to `NSOrdered*` in case some code returns 2 instead of NSOrderedDescending (NSComparisonResult is typedefed to NSInteger so this is potentially valid, and there's no protocol which says otherwise).

Comment: Well, since as you mentioned that in my solution `NSOrderSame` is safe, and since my solution doesn't have the case `if([a compare:b])` I think it doesn't deserve the -1 but it is important to add your valuable comments as comments under it :)